# Why model.fit() doesn't take a single input made of features and target in this case?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I attached code below for replicating the issue. The dataset comes from a Kaggle competition titled 'tabular playground series mar 2021.'

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, os
import tensorflow as tf
# Step 1. loading kaggle competition data
os.chdir('/kaggle/working')
train_df = pd.read_csv('../input/tabular-playground-series-mar-2021/train.csv', index_col=0)
cats = train_df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist()
# Step 2. label encoding
for c in cats:
    train_df[c], mp = train_df[c].factorize()
x_trn = train_df.drop('target', axis=1).values 
y_trn = train_df['target'].values 
# Step 3. creating the model 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(30,))) # we have only 30 features
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['AUC'])
model.fit(x=x_trn, y=y_trn, epochs=15)
```

The code above works. However, when I replaced the last line with the following command, the program broke. Can anyone let me know how to fix it?

```py
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_trn, y_trn))
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=15)
```

The error message complains about the incompatibility:

```sh
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 30 but received input with shape [30, 1]
```

The model architecture is listed below:

```sh
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 16)                496       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 136       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 641
Trainable params: 641
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The dimensions of features x and target y are:

```
print(x_trn.shape, y_trn.shape)
>>> (300000, 30) (300000,)
```

Comment: The error is stating that `.fit` expect the last dimension of the array to be 30 elements long, but you provided an array whose _first_ dimension had 30 elements and the last dimesion had 1 element

Comment: (also, don't post error messages and output as images. copy and paste the text. text is much easier to read and search for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with datasets in `model.fit`, TF expects the training dataset to be split in batches. Accordingly, to train you model add the following line before `model.fit()`:

```
   train_ds = train_ds.batch(your_batch_size).
```

This will produce data of the correct form. In your previous approach, TF automatically splited data in batches.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. My code finally runs. I'm just wondering about where you learn such a nuance. Read the source code?!

Comment: No, just had a similar issue. By inspecting tensor shapes and carefully reading API for `model.fit` (part on the batch_size, actually) I was able to solve it rather quickly. So, just careful debugging)